# Change fill color of a pie chart series in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, charts, pie-chart, color-scheme

I have a chart based on this query.

```
SELECT IDtrattativa, NomeCognome, [Ricavi] AS Valore, "Redditività" AS CostiRicavi FROM qryAnalisiOperazione
UNION
SELECT IDtrattativa, NomeCognome, [costi], "Costi" FROM  qryAnalisiOperazione;
```

It is a series, and this is what I get.
[image]

I want to change colors in the series (costi should be red and ricavi should be green).

I tried this code in open (then I tried in load event).

```
With Me.CostiRicaviGR.ChartSeriesCollection.Item(0)
    .BorderColor = RGB(123, 222, 100)
    .FillColor = RGB(200, 300, 111)
End With
```

Nothing happens.

Comment: Can you just set the colors in chart design instead of with VBA?

Comment: no, unfortunely

Comment: Interesting, I can with classic MSGraph.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this in my older version of Access (2016).   It seems that unlike Excel the Access Chart model doesn't support RGB.  But the Access Chart Model still supports the ColorIndex:

```
' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.colorindex
Private Sub cmdChangeColor_Click()
myGraph.ChartArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 4 'works 'sets the background of the chart
'myGraph.ChartArea.Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(4, 0, 0) 'works cast to 4
myGraph.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 5 'works 'sets the color of the data
End Sub
'to understand the model think of a pie chart like a line graph.  Each line on the line graph corresponds to a different Series or pie chart.  The first point is the first point on the line or the first piece of the pie.  Interior.ColorIndex sets the color of the line or pie piece.
```

[image]

[image]

The important caveat is that the Intellisense in my Access supported neither ChartArea or SeriesCollection and when I tried to wrap a ChartArea call in a function so I could pass it parameters it failed unexpectedly.  In short, this is an example of how the Access version of the chart object is far inferior to the Excel version.  Further Access programs work well together.

So the couple of times when I needed more than basic charting in Access I opened Excel behind the scenes and did everything there and just imported the finished chart into Access.  It took less than a second.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a specific example of making charts in Excel from Access but here is one link showing the basics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5LvSI4dIuc

Comment: Looks as if you are using the "old" chart objects. OP uses the "modern" charts (as far as I know, those didn't exist in 2016), and they work different.

Comment: thanks, actually i was trying not to use external programs, but maybe there is no solution inside access.